# android leanback browseSupportFragment return wrong selectedPosition?

Tags: android, row, android-tv, leanback

I am using a browseSupportFragment element in my android tv app having headers enabled and a single row for every header
the problem is when i select the first item of every row by scrolling down, or when i select a header of the header list, the function `getSelectedPosition` return 0 always

it return the right index of row when i select the second item in the row

i am pretty sure that this is a bug !!

below the code of onItemSelected

```
 @Override
public void onItemSelected(Presenter.ViewHolder itemViewHolder, Object
        item, RowPresenter.ViewHolder rowViewHolder, Row row) {

    int pos = getSelectedPosition();//this return 0 if i scroll down between headers
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to override it because for some reason it returns 0 by [default](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/1c3ce0f/v17/leanback/src/android/support/v17/leanback/app/BrowseSupportFragment.java).

```
    /**
    * Returns the selected position.
    */
    public int getSelectedPosition() {
        return 0;
    }
```

You might need to override the setter as well because it is empty too.

```
    /**
     * Selects a Row.
     */
    public void setSelectedPosition(int rowPosition, boolean smooth) {
    }
```

It seems leanback support was left a bit undercooked.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was need to add this peace of code

```
   @Override
public int getSelectedPosition() {
    return super.getSelectedPosition();
}
```